# Can you tame an ocelot but have it keep its original texture?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was wondering if you can tame an ocelot but still have its original texture?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocelot):

> The newly tamed cat will change to one of three breeds: [tabby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabby_cat), [tuxedo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuxedo_cat), or [Siamese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_cat).

There is no distinction made for PC version or PE, so my guess is, that it works the same way in all versions. Therefore, no, ocelots will change color upon being tamed.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a glitch way because my friend tamed some ocelots and when she came back into the world their textures where the original texture, I know the are no wild because they where all sitting.